# What does “Gurl” mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Katy Perry has a pop dance song titled *[California Gurls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F57P9C4SAW4)*.

What does *Gurls* mean in that context?

For me, after readying the lyrics, it's about California *Girls*; is this spelling  something Katy did just for fun?

Comment: You can type "define gurl" in Google and get this [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gurl) or [this](http://ko.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GURL). I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.

Comment: Michael, it's just fun spelling, like Ke$ha, or emoticons.

Comment: @Mitch wow what does Ke$ha mean?

Comment: @BrianDonovan well I didn't say anything wrong, you DO know Katy Perry even if you hate her (like me)

Comment: @michaelSalam https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesha

Answer (score 3):

Wiktionary has the following entry for [gurl](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gurl):

> **gurl** ‎(plural **gurls**) 1. (LGBT slang) Term of address between gay men. 2. (informal) A girl.

The same source gives the word's etymology as "Variant spelling of *girl*."

So, not much information there. The first pop song (that I'm aware of) to use the spelling was "[September Gurls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKFysCVWnVQ)" by Alex Chilton, a song that appears on the second Big Star LP, *Radio City* (1974). According to the [Wikipedia article on "September Gurls,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_Gurls)

> The title of Katy Perry's 2010 number one hit "California Gurls" was spelled as a tribute to Chilton and Big Star. Perry's manager is a fan of the band, and asked her to spell "girls" with a "u".

It's unclear why Chilton chose the spelling *gurls*, but *gurl* spelled with a *u* go back to at least 1840. From "[From a Servant of a Family Travelling to Astoria](https://books.google.com/books?id=nXkAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA379&dq=%22gurl%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7mYm1suPJAhUJw2MKHbouAsc4ChDoAQgiMAE#v=onepage&q=%22gurl%22&f=false)," in *The Dublin Magazine* (March 1840):

> Says he, 'I like you for that answer, my dear ; for it shows you are a gud gurl, such an uncommon pretty gurl as you (he said uncommon, I assure you—I am certain I can't be mistaken)—such an uncommon pretty gurl—(it was verry sivil of him to say so, when after all, I really do not think I am so verry, verry pretty)—such an uncommon pretty gurl as you are must take care of yourself ;' ...

Clearly people have been using the variant spelling *gurl* for a long time, whatever their particular reason for avoiding the standard spelling *girl* may be.

Comment: Maybe also because there already was a well-known song called California Girls (Beach Boys)?

Comment: Wow, it's accompanied by a lot of other [eye-dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) in that passage.

Comment: The passage appears to be a parody of a semi-literate person's mode of expression.